# re-write a URL and store the variable

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to re-write a url as follows...

**example input:**

```
test.com/test/123/
test.com/test/123/456/
test.com/test/123/456/789
```

**output:**

```
test.com/test/
test.com/test/
test.com/test/
```

But I would like to store the endings as a variable in the template on the test.com/test/ page

e.g

```
variable from input 1 : /123/
variable from input 2 : /123/456/
variable from input 3 : /123/456/789
```

is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried to do?

Comment: Yep, it's certainly possible

Comment: look at .htaccess and mod_rewrite

Comment: I have tried: RewriteRule ^test/(.*) /test/ [QSA,L]
then in the template
$var = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.str_replace('/test/','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
does this look along the right lines?

Comment: @scott Actually, your question is nice BUT I think, the details therein are incomplete.. Did you mean, to assign the part of a basename to a **PHP** variable? Or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as a start point: First your .htaccess receive the URL and then send it to a php script:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Skip virtual folders and files...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#Send the parameters to a php page
RewriteRule ^/test/(.*)/?$ http://test.com/test/index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then the php get the parameters as a string via $_GET

```
echo $_GET['route']; // '/123/456/789'
```

With that you could `explode()` the `/` and separate the variables.

Good luck.

Comment: i tried writing the htaccess like this, but the page isn't redirecting. could wordpress be overwriting this? thanks

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
#Send the parameters to a php page
RewriteRule ^/abc/(.*)/?$ /test/index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Use this with Wordpress may be dangerous. And try to put this rule as first